# how to add my custom html page (js and css) into wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a fully functional html page(js and css) working properly to my local browser. But I want to add this html file into wordpress page.

I tried to add the whole html code in wordpress page in text mode(not visual), but it not proper work. Js and css design not working.

So please guide me how to add this html page to work properly.

Thanks

Comment: Use an iframe maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Make a page template.

Use this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/page-templates/

> Page Templates within the Template Hierarchy #
>
> When a person browses to your website, WordPress selects which
>   template to use for rendering that page. As we learned earlier in the
>   Template Hierarchy, WordPress looks for template files in the
>   following order:
>
> Page Template — If the page has a custom template assigned, WordPress
>   looks for that file and, if found, uses it.
>
> page-{slug}.php — If no custom template has been assigned, WordPress
>   looks for and uses a specialized template that contains the page’s
>   slug.
>
> page-{id}.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s
>   slug is not found, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template
>   named with the page’s ID.
>
> page.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s ID is
>   not found, WordPress looks for and uses the theme’s default page
>   template.
>
> index.php — If no specific page templates are assigned or found,
>   WordPress defaults back to using the theme’s index file to render
>   pages.

To create a global template, write an opening PHP comment at the top of the file that states the template’s name.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```